# Como mejorar la precision de ubicacion usando Geolocation en ionic como la app de Google maps?

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic4

Tengo un problema tanto en android/ios para obtener la ubicación usando Geolocation, la precisión aveces es buena pero de ratos aveces la ubicación se va mas de 100metros del lugar donde estoy. Dividi mi pantalla usando la app de google maps donde la posicion se va moviendo e igual mi app donde solo estoy ocupando el metodo siguiente:

```
let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
watch.subscribe((data) => {
    this.positiongps = "lat: "+data.coords.latitude+" lng: " + data.coords.longitude;

});
```

Aveces paso la opciones `{enableHighAccuracy:true,timeout:5000}` al método watchPosition para mejorar la precisión pero sigue dando los mismos resultados. Acaso abra alguna otra forma de mejorar la precisión de ubicación así como la aplicación de google maps?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar añadir el parámetro `maximumAge` con un valor numérico alto, esto evita que salgan localización cacheadas.

```
{enableHighAccuracy:true,timeout:5000, maximumAge: 30000}
```

*Prueba bien el parámetro `enableHighAccuracy` creo que en versiones antiguas de android deja de funcionar el gps si esta parámetro esta activo.*

Deberías también asegurarte del que el usuario tiene el gps activo en modo Alta precisión (para los usuarios de Android) por lo menos que no este en modo ahorro de batería.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ultimo te recomiendo quitar los ahorros de batería que ponen las capas personalizadas en android. Para ello te recomiendo este plugin de cordova: https://github.com/thomas550i/cordova-plugin-doze-Optimize

PD: Si lo que quieres es hacer un tracker de gps para android te recomiendo este plugin ya que esta especialmente destinado para ello. https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation

Comment: Gracias, lo voy a intentar. tambien estuve probando lo de configurar android pero curiosamente cuando estoy conectado por wi fi funciona bien la localizacion pero usando los datos moviles aveces la precisión falla demasiado y aparece la ubicacion a 100 metros de donde estoy

Comment: Si, eso es por qué usa las antenas de redes móviles para geolocalizarse , en realidad te está mostrando aproximadamente donde se encuentra la antena de red móvil.

Comment: Entonces esta muy lejos de poder obtener la ubicacion aproximada porque lo que hago es verificar si la ubicacion esta dentro de un rango :/